# how to convert this sql query in laravel model

Tags: mysql, eloquent, laravel-5.8

hello guys I would like to convert this

```
SELECT count(*) from `customer` WHERE DATE(created_at) BETWEEN DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL -2 DAY) AND CURDATE()
```

how can i convert this to the laravel eloquent.

Comment: i dont have time for a proper answer but you use raw queries:
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#raw-expressions

Comment: What have you tried? This should be pretty simple, such as `Model::whereRaw(...)->count();` (you'll likely need `whereRaw()` are you doing MySQL-specific casting/date functions)

Comment: sorry i just newbie in laravel

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = DB::table($this->table)
        ->whereRaw('DATE(created_at) BETWEEN DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL -2 DAY) AND CURDATE()')
        ->count();
        return $data;
```